# How can I trigger javascript method while click on button event in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

A webpage(`.aspx`) which has a button along with `onclick` event which was working as expected. But, I'd like to access a `div` tag (status) at `javascript` method
when I click asp `button` (btnValidate).  My aim is hide/visible div based on the action happened inside code behind event.

How can I do this?

/** My Button Control Definition **/

```
<div style="top:0px;margin-top:0px;">
<asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" Text="Renew" 
CssClass="SubmitButton" onclick="btnValidate_Click"  />                     
</div>
```

/** Div status needs to be accessed in javascript when click asp.net button **/

```
<div id="status">
  <!-- Some control goes here for status -->
</div>
```

/** Button code Behind event **/

```
protected void btnValidate_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
  /** Some code goes here **/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either add `runat="server"` attribute to your `div` so it's accessible from code behind or put  it inside `<asp:PlaceHolder>` and change visibility of it.

You don't need to use javascript to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use registerstartupscript to run javascript from the codebehind

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx

for example:

```
protected void btnValidate_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "uniqueKey", "FunctionCall();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add runat="server" and id="[YourDivId]" in your div code.
Then place the div and the button in a common update panel.

The you use the div as an asp control in c# (ex: this.YourDivId.Visible = false;)

(There are other ways too.)